# 1,000 Feature Limit in AGOL - Find Nearest Tool

Tags: arcgis-online, network-analyst

I am trying to run the Find Nearest tool in ArcGIS Online. The tool's documentation does note that it will not run on layers with more than 1,000 features, but there are several Esri blog/Q&A's out there that have addressed this issue to offer work arounds. The solution was to publish the layer(s) as a hosted feature service either through ArcMap or from within Portal. I have done this and I still get the "Cannot process more than 1,000 records" error.

Does anyone know a proper workaround for this? I understand why they limit to 1,000 (because of drawing/rendering), but for a lot of cases, this would be exceeded by many users.

I do not have the Network Analyst extension for my desktop GIS to run this tool there, so I'm looking for alternative ways to compute a closest facility analysis.

My origin layer has 900 records, and my incidents layer has 11,000.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to display and for what purpose?

Comment: @MapLion what kind of question is it? OP defines the issue very clearly in my opinion.

Comment: When you publish / edit the service, look under the "Parameters" option and change the "Number of Records Returned by Server" from the default of 1000 to 20000. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Adjusting the records returned by server when publishing doesn't change the outcome, whether it's 1,000, or 12,000 records.